# Can't get PDO MySQL driver to work on PHP

Tags: mysql, php, mamp, pdo

Trying to install [Vanilla 2](http://vanillaforums.org/) locally using MAMP i got the error:
"You must have the MySQL driver for PDO enabled in order for Vanilla to connect to your database".

When I check phpinfo() I see:

```
--with-pdo-mysql=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library
--with-pdo-pgsql=shared,/Applications/MAMP/Library/pg
```

When I go and check out those paths I find the files:

```
libpq.5.dylib
libpq.dylib
libpq.5.2.dylib
```

When I check my php.ini file I see:

```
; Extensions
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

In php.ini the path to the extension dir is correct (checked it manually):

```
extension_dir = "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/"
```

In this folder I find the file:

```
pdo_mysql.so
```

phpinfo() gives me two sections:

```
PDO
PDO drivers: sqlite, sqlite2
```

and

```
pdo_sqlite
SQLite Library: 3.6.22
```

So everything seems to be fine, but can't get the PDO MySQL driver working :(

Comment: Solved!

phpinfo() showed:
Loaded Configuration File : /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5.3/php.ini 
but that folder did not exist (instead /Applications/MAMP/conf/php5/php.ini) did exist.

I've simply renamed the /php5/ folder to /php5.3/, restarted MAMP and everything worked!

Answer (score 1):

Note that pdo_mysql != pdo_sqlite. It does not appear that it is loading the PDO MySQL driver that Vanilla is looking for. It [wouldn't be the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175534/trouble-getting-mamp-to-work-with-pdo-mysql) that PDO-MySQL hasn't worked properly on MAMP.

I know with WAMP it has pre-compiled all of the binaries for you; it might not work in your specific environment because of this. I would recommend compiling PHP and the PDO-mySQL extension manually to make sure it will work.